# SQL: Select * where derivative of a a value within a certain time period is greater than x

Tags: java, sql, matlab, postgresql

Is there an easy way to do math queries in sql ?

For instance select * where derivative of a a value withing a certain time period is greater than x ?

Matlab can do this kind of stuff when connected to sql server, but is it possible to do without Matlab?

I am using Java and PostgreSQL for this.

**Example table:** 
(ticker, value, time).

Return all companies with an increase of value > 1.2 for 2012 - 2013.

Comment: Can you give an example table and output you desire?

Comment: Table: (ticker, value, time). Return all companies with an increase of value > 1.2 for 2012 - 2013.

Comment: Include the data types please. Sorry I am being pedantic.

Comment: it's (String ticker, double value, Timestamp time )

Comment: See this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156770/selecting-all-tickers-where-price-has-increased-by-5-percent-within-a-time-range