# Selecting all tickers where price has increased by 5 percent within a time range

Tags: sql, database

This one is not easy at all it seems.

I have a table **data**:

```
String ticker, Double price, Date time
--------------------------------------
```

How can I given the above table:

**SELECT ticker WHERE price has increased x percent AND time BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31'** ?

What one needs to do is for each ticker, determine the last and first value and divide them.

I have tried this but it is not working for obvious reasons:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ticker, min(ctid) as min, max(ctid) as max
    FROM data 
    WHERE 
    time BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31'  
    GROUP by ticker, time
    ORDER by ticker, time ASC
    ) X
WHERE 
    1.05 < (
        SELECT value
        FROM data 
        WHERE 
        time BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31'
        AND
        ticker = X.ticker
        AND 
        ctid = X.min
    )
    / 
    (
        SELECT value
        FROM data 
        WHERE 
        time BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31'
        AND
        ticker = X.ticker
        AND 
        ctid = X.max
    )
```

The above query is grouped by ticker and time, and the min and max are should be for the entire dataset. But I do get several tickers as a returned result, so I am not sure what is actually going on there.

I have also investigated doing this through WINDOW functions, there is a sample that's also not working:

```
SELECT 
ticker,
first_value(price) over W as first, last_value(price) over W as last 
FROM data 
WHERE 
time BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31'
WINDOW W as (
    partition by ticker, time
) 
ORDER BY ticker, time ASC
```

Does anyone know how to do this kind of query, on any database?

I am using PostgreSQL, why you are seeing **ctid** which in other databases is the same as **ROW_ID**.

But this problem is not related to PostgreSQL only.

**Dataset:**

```
create table data
(
 ticker varchar(5),
 price numeric(5,2), 
 time date);

insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1,'2014-10-01');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',0.95,'2014-10-02');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1,'2014-10-03');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1.04,'2014-10-04');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1.05,'2014-10-05');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1.06,'2014-10-06');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1.07,'2014-10-07');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1.09,'2014-10-08');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',2,'2014-10-09');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',2,'2014-10-10');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1.9,'2014-10-11');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1.8,'2014-10-12');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1.7,'2014-10-13');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1.6,'2014-10-14');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1.5,'2014-10-15');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1.4,'2014-10-16');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1.6,'2014-10-17');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1.4,'2014-10-18');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1.3,'2014-10-19');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('ABC',1.2,'2014-10-31');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('XYZ',.95,'2014-10-01');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('XYZ',1,'2014-10-31');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('PDQ',1.4,'2014-10-01');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('PDQ',1.3,'2014-10-31');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('XKCD',.01,'2014-10-01');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('XKCD',100,'2014-10-31');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('Z8T',1,'2014-10-01');
insert into data (ticker, price, time) values ('Z8T',1.04,'2014-10-31');
```

Comment: `foo between X and X`? why not just `foo = X`?

Comment: My mistake .. I will update ..

Comment: at any time it was over 5% (say it goes up 5% on 2nd day, then drops to baseline, should it show?)  or that on the end date it is over 5% of any starting price in the range (say it starts at 1.00 drops to .95 but then goes up to 1.00 again.  that's over a 5% gain. should the .95 to 1.00 show?)  I think you need to use a cross join when enddate > startDate

Comment: @xQbert It should only be for the entire range, which is why I do not believe window functions here are needed, however a window could be used for each ticker and entire dataset to possibly select last_value over each ticker data.

Comment: So you're really only interested in the price on the start date and price on the end date, and not the prices between.

Comment: @xQbert Yes, that is correct. Those prices should differ x percent. What tickers fullfill that criteria?

Comment: Something like this then? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/733d7/1/0  I don't think the cross join is needed in this case though if you are only interested in first and last dates...

Comment: Can you give example inputs and outputs

Comment: @Santhosh I have added a dataset for you in the question.

Comment: Is there exactly one price recorded per ticker per day? Are you guaranteed to have a price on 2014-10-1 and 2014-10-31? If these are true, then you can ignore all data not from those dates, which makes the problem much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In postgresql, we can efficiently perform a computational query as this:

Note, we are first selecting all the tickers from another table Ticker first, but this could be DISTINCT(ticker) on the data table as well.

```
SELECT A.name, A.symbol, B.price AS start, C.price AS last, D.percent from ticker A,

lateral ( SELECT B.price AS value from data B where  B.time BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-10' AND B.ticker=A.id ORDER BY B.time ASC limit 1 ) AS B,

lateral ( SELECT C.price AS value from data C where AND C.time BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-10' AND C.ticker=A.id ORDER BY C.time DESC limit 1 ) AS C,

lateral ( SELECT C.price / B.price AS percent ) AS D

WHERE D.percent > 1.05

ORDER BY D.percent DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably overkill using a cross join but I though you might be after any time in the range where a price compared to a future price for same ticker was greater than 5%

```
SELECT DS.Ticker, ds.Time as StartTime, ds.Price StartPrice, 
                  De.Time as EndTime, De.Price as endPrice, 
                  De.price/ds.price-1 as Growth
FROM data dS
CROSS JOIN data dE
WHERE dE > DS
and De.Price/DS.Price>=1.05
and DS.Ticker = DE.ticker
and DS.Time = '2014-10-01'
and De.Time = '2014-10-31'
```

I'm not sure how your between fits into this now though... and why would be using it..

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/733d7/1/0

Which is why I thought...

```
SELECT DS.Ticker, ds.Time as StartTime, ds.Price StartPrice, 
                  De.Time as EndTime, De.Price as endPrice, 
                  De.price/ds.price-1 as Growth
FROM data dS
INNER JOIN data dE
WHERE dE > DS
and De.Price/DS.Price>=1.05
and DS.Ticker = DE.ticker
and DS.Time between '2014-10-01' and  '2014-10-31'
and DE.Time between '2014-10-01' and  '2014-10-31'
```

might be what you're after instead.

Comment: This too, takes a very long time for a larger dataset. I wasn't actually able to complete the query.

Comment: changed cross join to inner on 2nd query.  though this will only return data if ticker has data on the 31st.  If you're after the last reported ticker price, we'd have to modify the query.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**
This solution assumes there is only one price recorded per day.

```
select
  Ticker,
  (LastPrice-FirstPrice)/FirstPrice rturn
from
  (select 
      Ticker,
      (select price 
       from data 
       where ticker = d.ticker
         and time BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31' 
       order by time asc
       limit 1) FirstPrice,
      (select price 
       from data 
       where ticker = d.ticker
         and time BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31'
       order by time desc
       limit 1) LastPrice
  from data 
  where time BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31' d) src
group by 
  Ticker,
  FirstPrice,
  LastPrice
```

**Solution 2**
This second solution for you to try, attempts to limit the result set earlier.

```
select
    Ticker,
    (LastPrice-FirstPrice)/FirstPrice rturn
from
    (select 
        m.Ticker,
        (select price 
        from data 
        where ticker = m.ticker
            and time = m.MinT) FirstPrice,
        (select price 
        from data 
        where ticker = m.ticker
            and time = m.MaxT) LastPrice
    from
        (select ticker, min(time) MinT, max(time) MaxT
        from data 
        where time BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31'
        group by ticker) m
     ) d
group by 
    Ticker,
    FirstPrice,
    LastPrice
```

Comment: I just tried this, it takes a very long time for a larger set of data. I presume that for each ticker in the Database it will run the two inner queries. So it will run the two inner queries n times of tickers in the database.

Comment: I have made a minor edit which should improve things a bit... please do let me know how you get on.

Comment: The minor edit mentioned in last comment was to the first solution, I have also added a second solution for you to try.

Comment: I was able to to perform an efficient query with something that is called LATERAL for Postgresql. It was added in 9.3 and allows you to basically perform any query on other selected data while building the other data. This allows you to basically run conditions while data is being looped through. See added answer.

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that there is exactly one price recorded per ticker per day, so you are guaranteed to have one price on 2014-10-01 and one on 2014-10-31 for each ticker, then you can ignore all data not from those dates, which makes the problem much easier. Assuming that:

```
select
    ticker
  , case when 
      price * 
      sum(
        case time
          when '2014-10-31' then 1
          when '2014-10-01' then -1.05
          else 0
        end
      )
      > 0
      then 1 else 0 end
      as HasIncreased
from data
group by ticker
```

This looks at the data table only once per ticker, so it should run relatively efficiently.